# Setting and Getting a Private Variable in the Module Pattern

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

Can someone explain why the private variable, _a, isn't being updated with the setter? I must be missing something really obvious but can't see it.

```
var f = function(a){
   var _a = a;

   return {
       getA : _a,
       setA : function(e){
          _a = e;
       }
   }        
};    

var d = f(1);
console.log(d.getA); // 1

d.setA(2);
console.log(d.getA); // 1
```

I thought that the second call should return 2

code here - http://jsfiddle.net/JUKWN/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second call to work, you need this:

```
var f = function(a){
   var _a = a;

   return {
       getA : function() {
           return(_a);
       },
       setA : function(e){
          _a = e;
       }
   }        
};
```

Your code is putting a static representation of the value of `_a` into the data structure that it's returning, not dynamically getting it's value from the actual source.  You need a getter function in order to dynamically get it's value for all data types.  What you had would actually work if _a had an array or object in it (because they are always by reference), but not when it's a simple type like a number or string (which is not by reference).

The code I've suggested will work for all values of `_a`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a real `getter` function. You're just assigning the value of `_a` to a property of your returned object literal. Modify your code like this

```
return {
   getA : function() {
       return(_a);
   },
   setA : function(e){
      _a = e;
   }
};     

var d = f(1);
console.log(d.getA()); // 1

d.setA(2);
console.log(d.getA()); // 2
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JUKWN/1/)